# Google Identity Platform -> Identity Provider

Tags: google-cloud-platform, keycloak, google-identity

We are thinking of using Google Identity Platform as our Customer IAM.

We have applications that could then use Google Identity Platform as their OAuth2 Authorization Provider (and also for OIDC Authentication) directly - applications that are only dealing with customers.

However, we also have applications that, today are using Keycloak as their OAuth2 Authorization Provider (and OIDC Authentication), where Keycloak is used as an Identity Broker, i.e. it will need to connect to the Customer IAM as well as to the Enterprise IAM so that Customers as well as employees (their identities are not in the Google Identity Platform) can be authenticated and authorized.

My questions: Can the Google Identity Platform be federated into Keycloak with other identity providers?
Or is there some other tool required in front of Identity Platform in order to achive this?

I found this article [GCP Identity Platform with Google IDP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62965416/gcp-identity-platform-with-google-idp), which is similar, but not same.

Thanks and regards
Kai-Uwe

Answer (score 1):

You can use Keycloak single sign-on(SSO) between Keycloak and your Cloud Identity (or Google Workspace account) by using SAML federation. Check this guide out [Keycloak single sign-on](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/identity/keycloak-single-sign-on)

Comment: This integration is only for Cloud Identity (the Enterprise IAM). It doesn't show how to handle the Identity Platform (the Customer IAM) part.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I have found the integration of KeyCloak with Cloud Identity, yes - but my question is for Cloud Identity Platform (the CIAM solution)